# In Rails, how can we pass parameters in script?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, parameters

In java script, I can define a variable.

```
var topping = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
```

And then, I want to use the topping value like this:

```
console.log(<%= @ecs.where(status:topping).count %>);
```

Obviously, it can't work because it will not find where is the topping. 
So my question is how should we use the parameters of script  in the <%=   %>.

Answer (score 2):

you probably confuse between server side script and client side script. <%= %> is server side script. javascript is client side script. When rendering a page, Ruby on Rails executes the server side script first, then send the response to your browser, YOUR BROWSER executes the client side script later, so you can't use client side variables in <%= %>.

If you want to get the result dynamically based on client side variables. Use AJAX. Send the parameter to the server, and get the response with javascript. It's a big picture. See tutorials below(not sure it will work) or start with a rails book(Agile Web Development with Rails) or google it.

[rails ajax tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-and-ajax.htm)